# Definite article "the" with places/buildings

Tags: articles

Could you tell if this is correct? Why sometimes the names of schools, museums and churches have the definite article while the others have not?

> Kazimierz Wielki Primary School in Przedbórz
>
> John Paul II Junior High School in Przedbórz
>
> Folk Museum in Przedbórz
>
> Church of Saint Alex in Przedbórz

Should I use "the" before the names? There is no "official name" in these cases (I mean whether is with "the" or not). What would you use?
I know that with "of" phrases the article "the" is used but I also found a confusing case:
In wikipedia there is the name:

> the Johns Hopkins University

but on their website there is:

> Johns Hopkins University

Could you explain this?

Comment: But I'd like the answer from native speakers what would they use in such cases? I'm not asking about the rules, but about these specific examples.

Comment: Hi, posting the same question is not allowed on Stack Exchange. Please delete this question on ELU. [Definite article “the” with places/buildings](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320123/definite-article-the-with-places-buildings). There is no hard and fast rule on using the definite article before a proper noun and you can search the internet for helpful references.

Comment: You will see a lot of links in the first answer of this ELU question, [Why does English use definite articles before certain proper nouns, such as the names of ships?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169970/why-does-english-use-definite-articles-before-certain-proper-nouns-such-as-the).

Comment: I ***am*** a native speaker! But since I don't actually *know* of "Johns Hopkins University", I've no idea whether they normally refer to the institution with an article or not. I can tell you that it's almost always ***The** London School of Economics*, but no-one ever includes an article with *Oxford University*, but you really need to just note how they refer to themselves and copy that.

Comment: @Rathony - Cross-posting questions is _discouraged_ on the Stack Exchange, but I wouldn't say it's "not allowed."

Comment: @J.R. Binary Misfit and Jeff don't agree with you in this [Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I asked the OP to delete the question on ELU in accordance with the Jeff's answer. The problem is the question is general reference and duplicate on both sites.

Comment: @Rathony - I'm well aware of that viewpoint. However, there is [more than one view on this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/4713#4713). More importantly, though, I was addressing the tone of your comment. The word "discouraged" is a more gentle rebuke than "not allowed," and **I think that might be a better way to phrase it in future comments.**

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to use the direct article as part of the *name* of schools, museums and churches. Thus I suggest the names of all four places  in Przedbórz are fine without *the*.

If you want to say you went to (attended or visited), you can also omit the definite article with the schools and the church. With *Folk Museum* it sounds more natural to me to say 'I went to the *Folk Museum*'. This is because "folk museum" can refer to a type of museum, a folk museum as opposed to a science museum.

As for universities in the USA, there is no rule. Some universities like to include *the* as part of their name. To some this is an attempt to sound "more special"  because the definite article refers to a specific (i. e., *one*) university, as in

> The Ohio State University

and

> The University of Texas at Austin

and other universities that include *the* in their official name. But outside of strict rigid adherence to official designations/names, people usually refer to them without the definite article or even their initials: OSU or UT.

(I have no idea what the "official" name of John Hopkins University is, but if it includes *the*, then it just works as the above two examples. And I believe the main concern of your question is whether you have to or should  include *the* as part of the English names of the four places in Przedbórz, and my answer to that, again, is no.)

The same thing applies to museums  some of which have *the* as part of their names and others of which do not. I suppose it's the same for churches, but I think the number of church buildings/congregations that use *the* as part of the name are few.

Comment: Technically, "The" **is** on the seal for Johns Hopkins and is an "official" part of their school's name and yet they don't use "The" on their website... whereas UT does... so that doesn't really help.